# Can I use the iPad Camera Kit to move photos onto an SD card?

Tags: ipad, photos, camera

Can the iPad Camera Kit be used to move or export photos onto an SD Card? I'd like copy photos from my iPad onto a memory card for a digital photo frame.

Answer (score 2):

you can read this [nice article](http://www.maclife.com/article/feature/seven_hidden_features_ipad_camera_connection_kit) of what can you do with such connector

in sum, you can:

- Attach USB Keyboards
- USB Audio Devices (like an usb wireless headphones)
- Attach a USB Microphone
- Removing Items from a Camera or SD Card
- Importing Photos from your iPhone or iPod touch
- External Hard Drive Support (Jailbreak hack needed)
- USB Hubs - Multi-device hookup

Comment: Many of those features were disabled by iOS 4.3.  Just FYI.  Evidently they reduced the power level supported by the Camera Connection Kit.  Many people found that their USB card readers no longer functioned.

Answer (score 1):

Apple only allows importing files. You are not able to export to a SD card.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please make answed focus on the question. Link-only answers are discouraged, but the other answer here is not only a link; it includes explanation of its own. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks!